# Change password complexity rules on GPO in windows server

Tags: passwords, active-directory

I need to customize the password complexity requirement in active directory GPO. But I cannot find the way to change the password complexity in GPO. The default password complexity contains

- Capital Letter (A-Z) -
- Small Letter (a-z)
- numbers(0-9)
- Any Special character(!,@,#,^,etc.,)

But my requirement is

- Capital Letter(A-Z)
- Samll Letter(a-z)

I check about my requirement in internet. But in internet, there is no built-in tool to change the password complexity. The customization of password complexity can be achieved by install password filter dll file with our requirement.

If anyone know well the answer about my problem, kindly answer my question.

Thank you

Comment: By default you can either enable password complexity or disable it, I never used the password filter and I think it is thought for more complex requirements. What are you gaining with your requirement? That people can not use numbers and special chars? This sounds like weakening the security  - so maybe you could just not use password complexity? Or create your pwd filter dll - Check out [MS Doc Site for Password Filters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secmgmt/password-filters)

Comment: No, I just put my password complexity requirement for testing purpose only. So I just check with this characters only. If it works fine, then i will strengthen my password complexity and then check with that.